# How to enumerate Network Shares running .Net Mono?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, network-programming, cross-platform

I recently looked into browsing Network (and Network Shares to enumerate folders and files onto them) running a .Net application and I found a solution that work fine for now using WMI or PInvoke. But I was wondering about cross-platform using Mono...

My solution seems to work only on Windows (but maybe i'm wrong ?), how to handle this properly to run on a Linux (and Windows as well) station ?

Should I detect the current OS and call a prompt for a standard command line tool which would be parsed to get the same result on different systems ?

For Linux, should I parse the result of smbclient from Process ? (See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-find-for-available-smb-shares.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the [Mono.Zeroconf](http://mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf#Listen_for_and_resolve_services) API was what I needed in order to discover network services (according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756825/need-samples-for-mono-zeroconf)).